# Getting an error while executing my python file which uses gym library for reinforcement learning

Tags: python, openai-gym

My python program :

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
env.close()
```

Error that I am seeing:

```
(base) Meets-MacBook-Pro:Documents meetpandya$ python gym-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl import *
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl.lib import GLException
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py", line 147, in <module>
    from pyglet.gl.lib_agl import link_GL, link_GLU, link_AGL
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib_agl.py", line 43, in <module>
    gl_lib = pyglet.lib.load_library(framework='/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework')
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 124, in load_library
    return self.load_framework(kwargs['framework'])
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyglet/lib.py", line 279, in load_framework
    raise ImportError("Can't find framework %s." % path)
ImportError: Can't find framework /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gym-test.py", line 5, in <module>
    env.render()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 240, in render
    return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 174, in render
    from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/envs/classic_control/rendering.py", line 27, in <module>
    raise ImportError('''
ImportError: 
    Error occurred while running `from pyglet.gl import *`
    HINT: make sure you have OpenGL install. On Ubuntu, you can run 'apt-get install python-opengl'.
    If you're running on a server, you may need a virtual frame buffer; something like this should work:
    'xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24" python <your_script.py>'
```

I have installed gym library successfully on my laptop. I do not understand the meaning of 'find framework /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework.'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as per this [thread](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/2101).

You will get an error `gym 0.17.3 requires pyglet<=1.5.0,>=1.4.0, but you'll have pyglet 1.5.11 which is incompatible` but the code should work now.

```
pip install pyglet==1.5.11
```

**Edit:**

This should work now

```
pip install --user --upgrade git+http://github.com/pyglet/pyglet@pyglet-1.5-maintenance
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried it but I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error. I believe the problem is not with pyglet but something to do with OpenGL

Comment: @MeetPandya are you using a M1 Macbook by any chance?

Comment: Nope. I'm using 2015 Macbook pro

Comment: I see is it on BigSur?

Comment: Yes. It is BigSur. Could that be the reason ?

Comment: Possibly but the updated answer is supposed to fixed issues with Big Sur. I will try it on my MacBook and see if there is any issue. It is weird as I was using openai-gym just a few weeks ago with no issue. Could you try it with version `gym==0.15.3`?

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. I look forward to your comments.